# ManytoMany Relationship in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have recently startet with Zend Framework 2 and came now across Doctrine 2, which I would now like to integrate in my first project.

I have now got the following situation and even after days, I can not find a solution.

I have 3 Tables:

Advert

```
advert_id
advert_title
etc
```

Category

```
category_id
name
label
etc
```

advert2category

```
advert2category_category_id
advert2category_advert_id
```

An Advert can be in different Categories and different Categories have different Adverts, therefore the table Advert2Category (ManytoMany).

After reading through the www, I have decided that it should be a ManytoMany Bidirectional, with the "owning side" at the Advert Entity.

Don't ask me why I decided that, I still don't understand Doctrine fully. Anyway, I created 3 Entities, but guess I only need Advert and Category Entity.

I now want the following to happen.

I click on a Category and want to see a list of Articles within this category., that means I have to read out the Table advert2category. I have created the Entities, here my Advert Entity:

So here is first my Advert Entity:

```
namespace Advert\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Advert
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="advert")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Advert
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="advert_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $advertId;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="advert_title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
     private $advertTitle;


    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="advertCategory", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="advert2category",
    * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert2category_category_id", referencedColumnName="category_id")},
    * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert2category_advert_id", referencedColumnName="advert_id")}
    * )
    */

    protected $category;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->category = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get advertId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAdvertId()
    {
        return $this->advertId;
    }


    /**
     * Set advertTitle
     *
     * @param string $advertTitle
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setAdvertTitle($advertTitle)
    {
        $this->advertTitle = $advertTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get advertTitle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAdvertTitle()
    {
        return $this->advertTitle;
    }


    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \Advert\Entity\User $category
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setCategory(\Advert\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \Advert\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

And my Category Entity:

```
namespace Advert\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Category
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $categoryId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;



    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Advert", mappedBy="category")
     **/
    private $advertCategory;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->advertCategory = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get categoryId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCategoryId()
    {
        return $this->categoryId;
    }


    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Just as a first test, I have now tried the following in my Controller:

//Below Controller now works to echo the  categories ArrayCollection

```
$data = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Advert\Entity\Advert')->findAll();

foreach($data as $key=>$row)
{

  echo $row->getAdvertTitle();
  echo $row->getUser()->getUsername();
  $categories = $row->getCategory();

  foreach($categories as $row2) {
    echo $row2->getName();
 }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone give me an advice? Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, and it's a very honest and fine thing, that this is way overcomplicating what you want to do, but only in specific areas.

If you used Composer to include Doctrine (the recommended way), also include `symfony/console` and you will get a whole mess of awesome tools to help you on your quest.  There is a very specific command that will kick you in your seat for how awesome it is: `$ doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql`. This will get Doctrine to run through your Entities (you only need the two) and will generate your tables and even setup the `*To*` associations for you. Int he case of `ManyToOne`'s it will generate the appropriate Foreign Key schema. In the case of `ManyToMany`'s it will automatically create, AND manage it's own association table, you just need only worry about giving the table a name in the Entity.

I'm not kidding you, Do this. It will make your life worth living.

As for your entity setup, this is all you need:

```
<?php 

namespace Advert\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Advert
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="advert")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Advert
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="advert_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $advertId;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="advert_title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
     private $advertTitle;


    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", cascade={"persist"})
    * @JoinTable(name="advert_categories")
    */
    protected $category;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->category = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get advertId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAdvertId()
    {
        return $this->advertId;
    }


    /**
     * Set advertTitle
     *
     * @param string $advertTitle
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setAdvertTitle($advertTitle)
    {
        $this->advertTitle = $advertTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get advertTitle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAdvertTitle()
    {
        return $this->advertTitle;
    }


    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param ArrayCollection $category
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setCategory(ArrayCollection $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

Notice that the getters and setters are Documented to Set and Return `ArrayCollection`, this is important for IDE's and tools that read PHPDoc and Annotations to understand how in-depth PHP class mapping works.

In addition, notice how much simpler the ManyToMany declaration is? The `@JoinTable` annotation is there to give a name to the table that doctrine will generate and manage. That's all you need!

But now, you probably should remove the `$advertCategory` property out of the Category Entity.  Doctrine is going to auto-hydrate embedded Entities in properties with the Entity Association Mappings.

This is also potentially dangerous as it can result in infinite recursion. Basically, if all you requested was an Advert with ID of 1, it would go in and find ALL of the Category Entities associated to Advert 1, but inside of those Categories it's re-referencing Advert 1, which Doctrine will sub-query for and inject, which will contain a Category association, which will then Grab those categories, and so on and so fourth until PHP kills itself from lack of memory.

Once everything is good to go, and you got some Categories associated with your Advert, using the Getter for your category in the Advert entity will return an array of Category Entities. Simply iterate through them:

```
foreach($category as $advert->getCategories()) {
   echo $category->getName();
}
```

or

```
echo current($advert->getCategories())->getName();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found it all very complicated as well, but I have tried multiple options. I have actually done some of the Entity set up through the console, but it did not set up my Relationships. It only created all the Getter and Setter. I will have to investigate a bit more. Anyway, I have changed the Code as you suggested, but I get again `Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection::getName()` and yes the missing () was my mistake when writing the Post, but was correct in the actual Sourcecode (Thanks anyway). Do I have to change something in the Category Entity?

Comment: +1 for such a nice answer... @Luka please do as he wrote I suspect you will be able to solve your issues

Comment: Okay, I must have done it wrong. I have changed the Primary Key in the advert and category table to be simply called id. I have deleted the Advert and Category Entity and recreated them with `orm:generate-entities ./module/Advert/src/ --generate-annotations=true`. I did not changed anything in the Entity, so I did not add any relationship. After that I deleted the advert2category db table and used the above `$ doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql`, which created me a new DB Table. But how do I now get the Relationships created automatically? I got lost here...

Comment: Personally speaking, I've never changed the ID field to be anything other than "id", it's unique to that table (and Entity) by nature anyways, never saw a need to change the names. Also, with `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")` I'd probably change that to "AUTO" for the both of them.   When using a `ManyToMany` field, it will automatically create that association table.  When you ran the command, the `--dump-sql` aspect was supposed to show you ALL of the queries that were going to be executed. Can we see that? If you dont have it, simply delete your tables and run the command again

Comment: Ok, so right now you have a couple of clean entities, with none of this silly ManyToMany stuff, is what im getting at from that reply, right Luka?  If so, literally all you need to do is manually add in a new property in Advert: `private $categories;` and give it the annotations 
`    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="advert_categories")
     */`  then run the schema update tool, with `--force` and `--dump-sql`. It will handle everything else, but you need to create the set/getters

Comment: You did have it right though with the construct, you need to initialize the property as a Doctrine ArrayCollection object. Make sure the Setters and Getters are expecting and returning that object specifically in the PHPDocs

Comment: I have tried all the above. I deleted the advert2category table and run the `doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql`. The table got created but I am shown an error message `An exception occurred while executing ALTER TABLE advert2category ADD CONSTRAINT FK_29C2C5B312469DE2 FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (id) ON DELETE CASCADE:SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Cant create table newbootsale.#sql-41c_1c7' (errno: 150)` another messages says `[PDOException]SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table newbootsale.#sql-41c_1c7 (errno: 150)`

Comment: As I said, the table advert2category gets created, but there seem to be problems with the FK. I have also added `public function setCategory(ArrayCollection $category)
{ $this->category = $category;
  return $this;
    }     public function getCategory()
    {
     return $this->category;
    }` Error Message is still `Call to undefined method getName()`

Comment: Ok, deleted all 3 tables and tried it again, this time no Error Messages from the doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql, but still the Call to.... error message. Any idea?

Comment: Oh, JEEZ, I can't beleive I hadn't thought of this before.  Your straight calling `$item->getCategory()->getName();` right? Well, actually yeah, it makes total sense that getName() wouldn't work, because your getting the Doctrine ArrayCollection back which is iteratable array. So:  `foreach ($category as $item->getCategories()) { echo $category->getName(); }`.  I have updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! I have added the echo current to my code above. Please have a look at the controller at my above code. Unfortunately I still have an Error message `Call to a member function getName() on a non-object`. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Ok, now I got it!! Please see above in the Sourcecode from the Controller. Is this okay? It works at least, not thinking of the fact yet that this was only to test if the ManytoMany Relationship works and what I actually want is not a findAll(), but to be able to show only the Adverts from the specific Category. This will be the next challenge. Thank you so much again for all your help. 2 weeks and close to give up totally frustrated and now it works. Thank you !!!